# tFileList into tFileInputXML is not working as expected

Tags: talend

I have a tFileList iterating over a set of XML files.

[image]

And for testing I have 1 XML file in the folder:

[image]

THe XML schema has a field called "operationresultdesc":

[image]

In my tJavaFlex, I am outputting the value of this field and it returns a null value (I am outputting "null apparently").

[image]

This "NULL" check should fail as I can see values in the field in the XML.

The weird thing is, if I add more XMLs file to the folder, the null failure "passes" to another file, and the one failing before apparently is not null any more.  This is the file which failed before with a null message, but now there is more than one XML file in the folder...no null issue (there never was a null issue, nor is there one in the file being flagged as null now).

[image]

For reference tJavaFlex code is:

[image]

UPDATE: This is based odd a repository XML schema driven off the XSD, and I do get the data flowing, the issue is the fact that I get a null when the file is on its own, but the same file works when I add more than one XML file in the folder...and the null failure passes to something else.

Feels like I am not understanding how the tFileList is iterating and how tJavaFlex is working in this case perhaps...but is very strange.

[image]

Comment: try to add a metadata of your xml (matadata > xml > right click > create) and add it to your xml input

Comment: Not sure what you mean, this is driven off a repository schema created from the XSD?  Why would it work correctly when there is more than one file if there are issues with metadata configuration of the XML?  Feels like this is something to do with how I am iterating and how tJavaFlex works in this use case?

Comment: instead of "== null" try to use "Relational.ISNULL(row1.operationresultdesc)"

Comment: I suspect this is related to me misunderstanding tJavaFlex.  It is null because the start code runs at the start of the sub job it seems not for each row.  I posted this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42425433/tjavaflex-behaviour-when-changing-loop-position/42435222#42435222