# tJavaFlex behaviour when changing loop position

Tags: talend

Having some problems in a job, and I suspect it is due to a lack of understanding of tJavaFlex.  I am generating 10 rows in this test job, and am generating loop inside a tJavaFlex:

[image]

So there are 10 rows coming in, and a loop in the Start and End section. I was expecting that for each row coming in, it would generate 10 identical rows coming out.  And that I would see iterations 0,1,2,3....9 for each row.

What I got was this.  This looks to me like the entire job is running 10 times, and so I have 100 random values coming through the flow from the tRowGenerator.

[image]

If I move the for loop into the Main Code section, I get close to the behaviour I was expecting.  I am expecting each row when it comes in to be repeated 10 times, and for 1 row coming in to produce 10 output rows.  What I get is this.

[image]

[image]

But even then my tLogRow is only generating one row for each 10 iterations it seems (look at the tLogRow output after iteration 9 above why not 10 items?).  I had thought I would be getting 10 rows for each single row coming in and I would see this in the tLogRow.

What I need to do is take a value from a field coming in, do some reg exp parsing and split into an array, and then for each item in the array create lines in the output flow.  i.e. 1 row coming in can be turned into x number of rows coming out using a string.split() method.

Can someone explain the behaviour above, and also advise on the best approach to get one value coming in, do some java manipulation and then generate multiple rows coming out?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you don't use it correctly.

- The initial part is for initiate variable. (executed one time before the first tow)
- In the principal you put your loop (executed one time at each row)
- In the final you store in global variable for example.(executed one time after the last row)

The principal code will be executed at each row in a tjavaflex. So don't put a for loop inside you can do like the example in the screen.

You tjavaflex comportement is normal. you have ten row so each row the for loop wil be executed 10 time (i<10)

You can use it like :

[image]

Comment: How do I generate more than one row out for each row in?  If I put the loop inside Code Pricipal - I guess I still only get one row out, I just assign the variables 10 time?  I need to split an incoming word into tokens and generate one row per word.  I don't want to use tSplitRow as I am also generating other content.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create your own loop.

By putting the for loop in the Start code, your main code will be triggered by the loop and by incoming rows, and it will be executed n*r times.

The behaviour of subjob that contains a tJavaFlex, reveils that component before tJavaFlex is included into its starting code, and the after component is included in the ending code, but that may depend to many conditions like data propagation and trigger type.

start code :

```
System.out.print("tJavaFlex is starting...");
int i = 0;
```

Main code :

```
i++;
System.out.print("tJavaFlex inside Main Code...iteration:"+i);
row8.ITEM_NAME = row7.ITEM_NAME;
row8.ITEM_COUNT = row7.ITEM_COUNT;
```

End code :

```
System.out.print("tJavaFlex is ending..."); 
System.out.print(row7.ITEM_NAME);
```

Comment: By putting the for loop in the Start code it appears to me the entire sub job is being executed 10 times.  Is this correct?  I read the code in Start and End fires at the start and end of the actual sub job? I do see 100 random strings from my tRowGenerator and not 10 strings repeated 10 times when my loop is in Start and End section.  I want to split an incoming value in a row into tokens and generate one row per token.  I don't want to use tSplitRow.

Comment: Please see updated answer, the last one need to be more explained in a separate question.

Comment: Thanks, this component is very badly documented.  Where in the documentation does it state that the component before and after is included in the starting code.  The documentation states: "Start Code:  Enter the Java code that will be called during the initialization phase."

Comment: I share the same idea, Talend is not well documented, I generally make a simple test job to understand a compoenent.

Comment: This is interesting, last example is a bit confusing why the second tJavaFlex "Start" fires before the first one:  https://www.talendbyexample.com/talend-tjavaflex-component-reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of main flow in row5, try using iterate flow to connect tJavaFlex