# How to sum inserted rows in tjavaflex component when iterating between inputs?

Tags: java, talend, data-integration

In Talend (open studio for data integration) 7.0.1 (and earlier versions). I use tJavaFlex to log how many rows have been inserted into a database.

Talend Job In detail:
1. Split large file into multiple smaller
2. Iterate between smaller files, insert them into database
3. Log how many rows have been inserted

[image: Talend job]

The logging part logs every iteration, to look like this:

```
2019-01-31 09:39:20 |Stage_SalesInvoiceLine | Rows inserted 5000
2019-01-31 09:39:25 |Stage_SalesInvoiceLine | Rows inserted 5000
2019-01-31 09:39:32 |Stage_SalesInvoiceLine | Rows inserted 5000
```

I need help figuring out how to get it to look like this:

```
2019-01-31 09:39:32 |Stage_SalesInvoiceLine | Rows inserted 15000
```

[tJavaFlex behaviour when changing loop position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42425433/tjavaflex-behaviour-when-changing-loop-position) I've tried to look here for an answer, but did not manage to solve my problem

Current code in tJavaFlex Main code part (start and end parts are empty)

```
Integer Inserted = ((Integer)globalMap.get("tJDBCOutput_6_NB_LINE"));
String InsertedS = "Rows inserted " + Integer.toString(Inserted);
row19.TimeStamp = TalendDate.getDate("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ");
row19.LogRow = "Stage_SalesInvoiceLine | " + InsertedS;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use local variables in tJavaFlex they will get reset at each iteration. Instead, you could define a global variable before the start of your subjob, increment it inside tJavaFlex, and retrieve its value after you've done all your inserts.

```
tSetGlobalVar (NB_INSERTS set to 0)
    |
OnSubjobOK
    |
database inserts -- OnComponentOK -- tJavaFlex
    |
tFixedFlowInput -- tFileOutputDelimited
```

In the above tJavaFlex, you can increment your variable in the main part:

```
globalMap.put("NB_INSERTS", (Integer)globalMap.get("NB_INSERTS") + (Integer)globalMap.get("tJDBCOutput_1_NB_LINE_INSERTED"))
```

in `tFixedFlowInput`: `"Rows inserted " + (Integer)globalMap.get("NB_INSERTS")`